# How to pass data in completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I'm trying to pass an IAP receipt to a `completion handler` that contains a user and would like to check if a users `subscription` is currently active by calling this in some other `class` I'm getting. How can I solve this.

> > Cannot call value of non-function type '((Student) -> Void)?'

```
func validateReceipt(pReceiptData: Data? = nil, completion pCompletion: ((Student) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let receiptData = pReceiptData!.base64EncodedString()
    let receiptDict: [String: Any] = ["receipt-data": receiptData]
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: receiptDict)
        guard let validationUrl = URL(string: "https://us-central1-myApp-a8e27.cloudfunctions.net/receiptValidation") else { return }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        var request = URLRequest(url: validationUrl, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = data
        let task = session.uploadTask(with:request, from: data) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let receipt = try IAPReceipt.decode(data: data)
                pCompletion(receipt)

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why is `pReceiptData` optional with a `nil` default value, although it's going to be forced unwrapped anyway. This makes no sense.

Comment: @vadian also he can set default value as empty closure `{ }` and then he can avoid optional parameter

Comment: @vadian its because I only need it in this currently call where I call. I won't need it another places thereby won't use it hence making it an optional and defaulting it to `nil`

Comment: `pCompletion` is optional, so it should at least be `pCompletion?(receipt)`, no? Also, I'd tend to make the `Student` param of the closure optional, and maybe use an error param, in case of error to make the completion called in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `typealias` to make your function declaration a bit cleaner. And take a look at how the completion block was made.

```
typealias Completion = ((_ student: Student) -> Void)?
func validateReceipt(pReceiptData: Data? = nil, completion: Completion = nil) {
      ...  
}
```